# Replace words taken from the list in txt file in python

Tags: python, text, replace

i have txt file with one word in each line (**library.txt**) like:

```
Word1
Word2
```

**Second txt** file look like this:

```
I have got many words. 
I know Word1 is very interesting.
ButWord2 is awful because its connected with another word.
I think there is no Word3 at all.
```

i need to search for those words from **library.txt** in **Second txt** file and replace them so those will look like this:

```
I have got many words. 
For example <font=yellow>Word1</font> is very interesting.
But<font=yellow>Word2</font> is awful because its connected with another word.
I think there is no Word3 at all.
```

Ive got such code but it doesnt work:

```
rules =[]
with open(library, 'r') as libraryfile:
    for line in libraryfile:
        rules.append(line.rstrip())

with open(second', 'r') as secondfile:
    with open(third', 'w') as thirdfile:
        for line in secondfile:
            if all(rule in line for rule in rules):
                thirdfile.write(line.replace(rule, '<font color=yellow>'+rule+'</font>'))
            else:
                thirdfile.write(line)
```

Comment: After `second` and `third` there shouldn't be any `'`.

Comment: sorry for the misspelings. in my code i dont have them. its not the case of the filename :) but thanks!

Comment: You `if all` line is checking whether all words exist on a single line, then tries to use the variable "rule" which shouldn't be defined in that scope. You want `for`, not `if all...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to use `any` and not `all`. As you want at least one of them to be in `rules` to make changes.
Then `rule` is not defined outside of `if`, plus you might have several words from `rules` to replace in `line`, so best is to iterate over `rules` and replace when needed. This gives:

```
with open(second, 'r') as secondfile:
    with open(third, 'w') as thirdfile:
        for line in secondfile:
            if any(rule in line for rule in rules):
                for r in rules:
                    line = line.replace(r, '<font color=yellow>'+r+'</font>')
            thirdfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `any` instead of `all`, as it is enough for **one** of the words from `rules` to appear in a line.